# Toggle Slide Navigation Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm having an issue with this code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $active,
    togglerSelector = '.gHdr .gMain .gHolder nav#gNav-primary-nav .nav-primary li a',
    toggledSelector = '.gHdr .gMain .gHolder nav#gNav-primary-nav .nav-primary li ul',
    $items = $(togglerSelector),
    animationDuration = 300,
    activeClassName = 'gActive',
    activeStyle = {height: auto},
    notActiveStyle = {height: 0},
    hideActive = function() {
        $active && $active
            .stop()
            .animate(notActiveStyle, function() {
                $(this).removeClass(activeClassName).hide();
            });    
        $active = void 0;        
    },
    showActive = function($element) {
        $element && ($active = $element)
            .stop()
            .show()
            .animate(activeStyle)
            .addClass(activeClassName)
    };

$items.on('click', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $overlay = $this.children(toggledSelector),
        theSame = $overlay.is($active);
    hideActive();
    theSame || showActive($overlay);
});
$(this).on('click', function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target),
        isOutClick = !$target.closest(togglerSelector).length;
    isOutClick && hideActive();
 });
});
```

I need the navigation to detect the height by itself and I just cant anything around the web to help me, it seems to be proving quite difficult.

The code is basically the navigation of my site, When someone clicks on a dropdown link it slides down and if the click on the page off the nav it slides back up. It also allows them to switch nav. Sorry if this answer isnt very clear. I have the nav elements set to `display:none;`

Comment: i'm reviewing your post, which selector, I mean Html element do you want to track?

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the trigger href is set to href="javascript:void(0);" if thats any curtsy

Comment: @Balder The Trigger I want to track is the anchor ref

Comment: every anchor inside the li, right?

Comment: @Balder No just the `.nav-primary>li>a`

Comment: Ok, I just dont get why you are using such a complex selector in jquery, instead of just a $('.nav-primary a') for example

Comment: @Balder I've made a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gzhy92ym/

Comment: @Balder If you look here this is how our site looks like but with out additional content like URLS, Logos etc. https://fiddle.jshell.net/gzhy92ym/show/

Comment: Ok, I can understand it better let me take a look

Comment: So you want to show the hiden ul when i click in Shop right?

Comment: Yea, but also when you click on "My Account" I want to show you "Shop" `slideUp()` and "My Account" `slideDown()`

Comment: here is a first approach: http://jsfiddle.net/a2e7urrg/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some tweaking around with some new code I came up with this solution...

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
        var child = $(this).index('nav ul li a.toggle');
        if ($(this).siblings('.dropdown').is(":visible")) {
            $('.dropdown').slideUp(200);
            $('.toggle').removeClass('nActive');
        } else {
            $('.dropdown').slideUp(200);
            $('.toggle').removeClass('nActive');
            $('.toggle:eq('+child+')').addClass('nActive');
            $('.dropdown:eq('+child+')').slideDown(350);
        }
    });
});
```

This solution allows me to use `slideDown()` to add a nice elegant effect to the navigation items and toggle on the classes to the correct corresponding dropdown menu.

I was planning on adding a `mouseout` feature to toggle the class and `slideUp()` the dropdown menu - but it didn't seem to work properly or as efficient.

You can find my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/a2e7urrg/7/

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the most of the work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(".toggle").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        //deactivate
        $(".toggle.active").next().toggle();
        $(".toggle.active").toggleClass("active");        

        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });    

   $(".submenu").on("mouseout", function (e) {
        $(this).toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggleClass("active");
    }); 


});
```

I just added a class named "toogle" to those anchors you want to have this behaviour, like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toggle">Shop</a>
```

Edit: I added a submenu class for the `<ul>` to make it work with the mouseout event

```
<ul class="submenu">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a2e7urrg/4/

I didn't add the animation, but is pretty easy to do it, you can just add the animation to the css class `active`.

Comment: How would I get it to be removed if clicked again or if the user doesn't click on the navigation area atall? http://jsfiddle.net/a2e7urrg/3/

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: maybe you could use a timer

Comment: @How would I do that? Could you show me a link of some sort??